# Filtering a JSON by attribute

Tags: jquery, json, filtering

I have the following json data:

```
   "unit 251":{
      "path":"M256.57 475.46L251.00 478.71L248.15 478.14L245.46 474.81L253.62 468.11L254.07 467.73L256.10 470.18L256.12 470.20L257.48 470.41L257.48 470.41L258.49 471.59L259.64 472.92",
      "name":"unit 251",
      "status":"Avaliable",
      "color":"#006738",
      "size":"3200",
      "price":"300 000"
   }
```

A lot more though... And I need to in jquery add a class of available, in order for me to do that i need to some how sort the array by status. i am currently trying with the following code:

```
    //Filter By Status
    function filterUnitStatus(unitStatus){
        jQuery.grep(json['properties'], function(item){
            return item.status == unitStatus;

        });
    }
    //Filter By Status

    jQuery('#status').on('change', function(){
        var unitStatus = jQuery(this).val();
        filterUnitStatus(unitStatus);
    });
```

But I don't quiet know what I am doing.

Any Help Greatly Appreciated

Comment: what is #status? can you please provide a fiddle with a little bit of working code? www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: `return` the `jQuery.grep` since that is returning an array. As of now, that function returns nothing.

Comment: well undefined, it is a valid json array i just tried to simplify it by not posting 62 lines of just json array...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not returning anything from your function, the `.grep()` create's an array, so return that! Also, the `.grep()` wasn't returning anything, I modified it to work by getting the JSON objects keys and iterating:

```
//Filter By Status
function filterUnitStatus(unitStatus){
    return jQuery.grep(Object.keys(json), function(item) {
        return json[item].status == unitStatus;
    });
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ntTTp/

Comment: how would i see that data?

Comment: im doing: console.log(filterUnitStatus(unitStatus)); but i get []

Comment: Then your `.grep` isn't returning anything.

Comment: @DawidvanderHoven -- I fixed your `.grep()` and changed the answer, also gave a demo, check it out, let me know if it's all good!

Comment: The `return json[item].status = unitStatus;` will return a `true` equivalent value for *every element* in the array that has a `status` property. You should use `return json[item].status == unitStatus;` instead.

Comment: @cars10 -- good catch, didn't notice that missing `=`, edited.

Answer (score 0):

Your filter function did not return anything at first, change it to

```
function filterUnitStatus(unitStatus){
    return jQuery.map(obj, function(el){
        if (el.status == unitStatus) return el;
    });
}
```

`jQuery.grep()` only accepts real arrays as arguments. Use `jQuery.map()` instead. This will walk through arrays or objects and return an array with all the matched *objects* in it.

The solution provided by tymeJV contains all the *names* of matched objects, which was apparently what the OP wanted. The same result can be achieved by modifying the above to

```
function filterUnitStatus(unitStatus){
    return jQuery.map(obj, function(el,id){
        if (el.status == unitStatus) return id;
    });
}
```

Now the returned array will contain only the *matched keys*.

See here : http://jsfiddle.net/ntTTp/2/

Comment: looks like I was a second too slow ;-)

Comment: how would i see that data?

Comment: im doing: console.log(filterUnitStatus(unitStatus)); but i get []